# Does the diophantine equation $\,\prod_{k=1}^n(p_k^{x_k}-1)=y^2\,$ have always at least a solution for $\,n\gt2\,$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

P.G.Walsh proved [in this paper](https://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/gwalsh/slov1.pdf) that the diophantine equation $\,(2^{x_1}-1)(3^{x_2}-1)=y^2\,$ has no solution in positive integers $\,x_1$, $\,x_2\,$ and $\,y$.

If we generalize the previous equation to the following (in $\,n+1$ variables: $\,x_1,\,x_2,\,...,\,x_n,\,y$)
$$\prod_{k=1}^n(p_k^{x_k}-1)=y^2$$
($p_k$ being the prime of index $\,k$) positive integer solutions appear. For example:
$$n=3\;\;\rightarrow\;\;(2,2,2)\;\;\;\;y=24$$
$$n=4\;\;\rightarrow\;\;(2,1,1,1)\;\;\;\;y=12$$
$$n=5\;\;\rightarrow\;\;(2,4,1,1,1)\;\;\;\;y=240$$
$$n=6\;\;\rightarrow\;\;(1,4,1,1,1,1)\;\;\;\;y=480$$
$$n=7\;\;\rightarrow\;\;(1,4,1,1,1,1,1)\;\;\;\;y=1920$$
**Does the diophantine equation
$$\prod_{k=1}^n(p_k^{x_k}-1)=y^2$$
have always (at least) a solution for $\,n\gt2\,$?**

Many thanks.

Comment: It's immediate to find a solution for $n=8$, but I haven't found any for $n=9$.

Comment: For $n=9$, one has $(10,4,3,1,1,1,2,1,2)$ and $y=141419520$.

Comment: For $n \leq 14$, it is not too hard to find solutions. For $n=15$ (and likely $n \geq 15$), it seems to be rather trickier (one ends up playing a game of primitive divisor "whack-a-mole"). I suspect that no solutions exist, but proving this would be, I would suppose, beyond current technology.

Comment: For $n=10$, solution is $(10, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), y=1319915520,$  
     For $n=11$, solution is $(10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), y=6310351111680,$  
     For $n=12$, solution is $(10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), y=37862106670080,$  
     For $n=13$, solution is $(10, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1), y=13000639905792000,$  
     For $n=14$, solution is $(10, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), y=475169587200$

Comment: @MikeBennett one assumes that primes can be **chosen,** instead of consecutive beginning at $2,$  to arrange square for all the $x_i = 1,$ separate problem all $x_i = 2,$  and so on. Actually, I've done something similar, make a list of the first many primes and all prime factors of  each $p-1$ for one problem or $p^2 - 1;$   then linear algebra over the field of two elements. Ordinary row reduction works very well.