# Does the equation in positive integers $(n,y)\,\prod_{k=1}^n(p_k^2-1)=y^2\,$ only have the solution $(3,24)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

**Does the equation in positive integers $\,(n,\,y)$
$$\prod_{k=1}^n(p_k^2-1)=y^2$$
only have the solution $(3,\,24)\,$?**

I asked a more general [question here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379789/does-the-diophantine-equation-prod-k-1np-kx-k-1-y2-have-always-a).

The computational complexity of the problem can be slightly reduced considering that
$$(2^2-1)(3^2-1)(5^2-1)=24^2$$
$$24|p^2-1\;\;\;\;\;p\gt3$$
Therefore, one can consider the equivalent problem
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{2n+3}(p_k^2-1)}{24^{2(n+1)}}=z^2$$
and the known solution $\,(n,\,z)=(0,\,1)$.

**Up to $\,n=5\cdot10^4-2\,$ I have not found any other solution.**

Many thanks.

Comment: Probably no, but looks hopeless. There should be many primes for which $2p+1$ is prime and $4p-1$ is too large.

Comment: To expand on @FedorPetrov 's comment. the density of Germain primes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes strongly suggest that for any such product which is sufficiently large, one will have at least prime p where $p^2 -1$ is divisible by a very big prime tha has not shown up anywhere else in the product.

Comment: This may have something to do with Mihailescu theorem (former Catalan conjecture), if we manage to prove $p_{k}^{2}-1$ has to be a perfect power as well as a divisor of $y$ for some $k$.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer - only posting here since no pictures can be placed in comments

[image]

That the $n$th row of the above picture has black pixel at the $m$th position means that the $m$th prime has odd multiplicity in $\prod_{k\leqslant n}(\mathrm{Prime}_k^2-1)$.
So a counterexample would mean having an entirely white horizontal line.

The widening black streak to the right actually comes from a string of $1$s; that is, the larger and larger amount of highest prime divisors all have multiplicity $1$. Should be not entirely impossible to show this. Actually, it obviously suffices to show that the highest prime divisor has multiplicity $1$.

Comment: I'm not sure this graph is helpful: I think a random number of a given size will display a similar behavior (i.e. listing the parity of the times each prime divides it, one would get a row similar to the ones in this graph for the corresponding size). In particular it will have several "ones" on the right.

Comment: @JoelMoreira Well the fact is the number of ones to the right grows for this particular sequence; you may interpret this as saying that this sequence consists of "typical" numbers for their size; if this can be made rigorous it would suffice to prove what one needs.